# Rails: undefined method `inject' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to sum up the minutes_out per day with this:

```
<%= @activities.where(created_at: date.midnight..date.end_of_day).map(&:minutes_out).compact!.inject(0){ |sum, i| sum + i } %>
```

The error I'm getting is:

> undefined method `inject' for nil:NilClass Did you mean?  inspect

Comment: Try `compact` without the `!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why this much complex calculation? if minutes_out is integer

```
@activities.where(created_at: date.midnight..date.end_of_day).sum(:minutes_out)
```

will give you an answer.

Answer (score 4):

`compact!` returns `nil` if there were no duplicate. Use `compact` instead:

```
<%= @activities.where(created_at: date.midnight..date.end_of_day)
               .map(&:minutes_out)
               .compact
               .inject(0) { |sum, i| sum + i } %>
```

Just a side note: Some might argue that having such complex queries in the view is a code smell. It might be better to move the query into the controller or as a method into a model.